# Clarification of Contour Integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I apologise if this seems like an elementary and silly question, but I am confused about the integral
$$I=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos{x}}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{e}$$
If I consider a semicircular contour with infinite radius in the upper half on the plane, I can write
$$I=\Re\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}dz=\Re\left[2\pi i\lim_{z \to i}\frac{e^{iz}}{z+i}\right]=\frac{\pi}{e}$$
since the integral over the arc vanishes as the radius approaches infinity. However, I get an incorrect result if I instead use the integral
$$I=\oint_C\frac{\cos{z}}{1+z^2}dz=\pi i\lim_{z \to i}\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{z+i}=\frac{\pi}{2}(e+e^{-1})\neq \frac{\pi}{e}$$
May I know where I have made a mistake? Why are we not allowed to use (or are we?) $\cos{z}$ directly in the complex integrand but have to use $e^{iz}$ instead and extract the real part? And why is it that the 2 answers turn out to be different? Help offered to clarify my doubts will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738139/how-does-the-integral-int-d-c-eia-zpz-q-z-mathrmdz-blow-up). The term $e^{-iz}$ is unbounded on the semicircle in the upper half-plane, so the integral over the semicircle doesn't tend to $0$ anymore.

Comment: $I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2(1+z^2)}dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}dz= 2\pi i \frac{\pi}{e}=\frac{\pi}{e}$